# LEFT used in subquery

Tags: sql-server

My problem is quite simple. The following query returns the error:

> Mensagem 537, Level 16, state 2, Line 1
> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function..

Code:

```
Select  
  c.name "Nome Conta",
  c.code "Código Conta",
  sq1.[Nome Conta] Tipo

From
  (chart_tag ct inner join chart c on ct.id_chart = c.id_chart) inner join
        (Select  
            c1.name "Nome Conta",
            LEFT(c1.code, (charindex('00', c1.code)-1)) "Código Conta"

         from chart_tag ct1 inner join chart c1 on ct1.id_chart = c1.id_chart

         where ct1.id_tag = 18159 and
               c1.id_type_chart = 1942 and
               c1.only_accrual = 1 and 
               c1.code not in ('99', '98')) sq1 on LEFT(c.code, 1) = sq1.[Código Conta]

Where
  ct.id_tag = 18159 and
  c.id_type_chart = 1942 and
  c.only_accrual = 0

order by
  c.code
```

The first inner join returns the following table:

| Name | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Caixa Geral | 1111001 |
| Caixa Departamentos/Operador | 1111005 |
| Valores Recebidos a Depositar | 1111025 |
| Bancos Conta Movimento | 1112001 |
| Bancos Conta Movimento - Vincul | 1112005 |
| Bancos Conta Subvenções | 1112021 |
| Bancos Conta Doações | 1112022 |
| Bancos Conta Contribuições | 1112023 |
| Aplicações Financeiras Imediata | 1113001 |
| Aplicações Financeiras Vinc. | 1113005 |

Executing the From subquery separately no errors are returned. The following table is generated:

| Name | code |
| --- | --- |
| ATIVO | 1 |
| ATIVO CIRCULANTE | 11 |
| CAIXA E EQUIVALENTES | 111 |
| CAIXA | 1111 |
| BANCOS | 1112 |
| APLICAÇÕES FINANCEIRAS | 1113 |

From

| Name | code |
| --- | --- |
| ATIVO | 1000000 |
| ATIVO CIRCULANTE | 1100000 |
| CAIXA E EQUIVALENTES | 1110000 |
| CAIXA | 1111000 |
| BANCOS | 1112000 |
| APLICAÇÕES FINANCEIRAS | 1113000 |

Subquery:

```
Select  
  c1.name "Nome Conta",
  LEFT(c1.code, (charindex('00', c1.code)-1)) "Código Conta"
    
from
  chart_tag ct1 inner join chart c1 on ct1.id_chart = c1.id_chart
    
where
  ct1.id_tag = 18159 and
  c1.id_type_chart = 1942 and
  c1.only_accrual = 1 and 
  c1.code not in ('99', '98')
```

Changing the main logic, which is to remove the '0' to the right of the "code" column, to use replace the query is executed normally and returning the expected result, except for some lines that deviate from the pattern, containing '0' in the middle of the string , and not just right. Because of this, I thought I'd use the current logic, which is returning the error. Knowing this, the LEFT to which the error refers is that of the subquery, however, as already mentioned, as it is an isolated subquery, which does not depend on external factors, I do not understand the reason for this error.

Comment: What happens if the c1.code column does not contain '00'?

Comment: But in this case all lines will have at least one '00'. Executing only the snippet that contains the LEFT no error is returned. That is the problem. If it wasn't like that I would understand that in the middle of the process the query found a row that doesn't contain '00' in that column, but the query ends normally when executed outside the From

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, if you're simply trying to remove the trailing 0 from the number, have you considered:

```
REPLACE((RTRIM(REPLACE(c1.code, '0', ' ')),' ', '0')
```

Change all the 0 to spaces, TRIM, and change residual spaces back..

There'll be more ways to skin the cat;

```
REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(c1.code) as INT))
```

(but reverse is generally regarded as a bit nasty/slow) etc..

Comment: Perfect, friend! How did I not think of that first option you gave? But I'm still wondering why this error is occurring.

Comment: I thought my other answer went into some detail about why the error occurs... Somewhere one of the rows in your table will have a value that doesn't contain 00, like `1112021` - when this happens, CHARINDEX returns 0, and because you -1 off it, the result comes to -1, which is then given as the length argument to LEFT function, except 0 is the lowest allowed value for lenght - you can;t take -1 chars off the left of a string, so it comes to an error

Answer (score 0):

So, here's how to debug this:

- When you don't use LEFT, you don't get the error
- The error message complains that the length passed to LEFT is invalid
- The problem is with the LEFT function
- The length is passed as the second argument

Replace the `c1.code` with some value:

```
Select  
  LEFT('100', (charindex('00', '100')-1)) "Código Conta"
```

It works, gives you 1

But.. What if the string you seek isn't found in the value?

```
Select  
  LEFT('199', (charindex('00', '199')-1)) "Código Conta"
```

"Invalid length..."  error

So what length are we passing? Extract just the length calc:

```
Select  
  charindex('00', '199')-1)
  --LEFT('199', (charindex('00', '199')-1)) "Código Conta"
```

It gives -1, and -1 isn't a valid number of chars to remove from the left of something...

So what do you want to do when the needle isn't found in the haystack? Perhaps take the whole string with no substringing? Or maybe adjust the WHERE clause to only allow codes that end with a 00, so the seek always works?

You decide.. This will give you the whole thing if '00' isn't found:

```
Select  
  LEFT(
    c1.code, 
    COALESCE(
      NULLIF(
        charindex('00', c1.code)-1,
        -1
      ),
      LEN(c1.Code)
    )
  ) "Código Conta"
```

If the seek returns `-1` meaning "asn't found", `NULLIF` converts the -1 to `null`, and `COALESCE` then converts the `null` to the `LEN` of the string, i.e. `LEFT` returns the whole thing

This will give empty string if the string isn't found; the only difference is use use of 0 in the coalesce - it asks LEFT to give the leftmost 0 chars:

```
Select  
  LEFT(
    c1.code, 
    COALESCE(
      NULLIF(
        charindex('00', c1.code)-1,
        -1
      ),
      0
    )
  ) "Código Conta"
```

Or, as mentioned, use a `WHERE c1.code LIKE '%00%'` to ensure youre only looking at codes that really do have 00 in them

Comment: I don't think nullif will work since charindex returns 0 which is not null

Comment: Youre getting confused with `IFNULL`. `NULLIF` converts a value to `NULL` if it is a certain value, in this case -1. It is a way to avoid doing the CHARINDEX twice

Comment: You are right -- I was getting those switched.  But why does doing them twice matter?  Any optimizer will store the value and only do it once.

Comment: Well, I didn't write the optimizer, nor have I read the source code/an authoritative reference that says it's the case so I can't guarantee that.. But I've no problem with you asserting it! :)

Comment: It was standard level 0 optimization when I took a compiler course 25 years ago -- so I think it is a fair guess.  I think it was called sub-expression optimization -- not sure, it was a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not have the substring '00'

```
LEFT(c1.code, (charindex('00', c1.code)-1))
```

Will give an error since it return 0 and -1 is not valid

This will work:

```
CASE WHEN charindex('00', c1.code) > 0 
     THEN LEFT(c1.code, (charindex('00', c1.code)-1))
     ELSE c1.code
END
```

This will also work:

```
LEFT(c1.code+'00', (charindex('00', c1.code+'00')-1))
```

I believe the 2nd one will be faster but it may not be based on your data profile so if performance really matters test both.